# In elasticsearch I want to query where I filter data with term and if term is not passed it should ignored it

Tags: json, elasticsearch, lucene

I using multi_match query and I am getting results properly, however, when I try to add the filter to the query I am getting results but what I want is that if one term is not passed in the filter it should not give an error and ignore it.

I have tried using bool should and filter within filter but I am still getting the error. Below is what I have so far:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "multi_match": {
          "fields": ["name", "tags"],
          "query": text,
          "fuzziness": "AUTO",
          "operator": "and"
        }
      },
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "active": true
          },
          "term": {
            "enable": true
          },
          "term": {
            "category": "xxxxxxxx"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "name",
    "_id",
    "productImageURL",
    "inflationPrice",
    "discountedPrice"
  ],
}
```

Comment: Can you give some more information about the error you are getting?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by passing the category as conditional in function.